# React custom controlled form component events

Tags: reactjs

When we use the builtin HTML input components, the `onChange` listener is given an instance of [`SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), which allows us to do things like

```
onChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  })
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="username" 
        value={ this.state.username }
        onChange={ this.onChange } />

      <input 
        type="password" 
        name="password" 
        value={ this.state.password }
        onChange={ this.onChange } />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notice that I can use the same listener for multiple form controls. However, if we use a custom form control, say, a DatePicker or something more domain-specific like UserSelector, these components usually have their own API to handle changes (e.g., `onChange(newValue)` or `onChange(oldValue, newValue)`). This forces me to write one listener per field.

Is there any good way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to construct your own data structure to emit that is similar to an event.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

const onChange = component => event => {
  component.props.onChange({
    target: {
      value: Object.assign({}, component.props.value, {
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      })
    }
  })
};

export default class UserControl extends PureComponent {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input name="name" value={this.props.value.name} onChange={onChange(this)} />
        <input name="age" value={this.props.value.age} onChange={onChange(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Your custom event object can pluck other keys of React's synthetic event as required.

Note that the onChange handler doesn't have to be tied to a class. Since it's generic, it can exist as a separate bit of code that accepts a component first.

**EDIT:** One thing to consider is to also pass along the stopPropagation method in case it's needed. I haven't had to do this myself yet, but this seems to work. Note the event.persist(). This ensures the SyntheticEvent is not reused by React.

```
const onChange = component => event => {
  event.persist();
  component.props.onChange({
    stopPropagation: event.stopPropagation.bind(event),
    target: {
      value: Object.assign({}, component.props.value, {
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      })
    }
  });
};
```